# Does python threading work with gunicorn?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, python-multithreading

I'm developing a web app in flask and I'm not sure if my code will work on gunicorn3 nginx server because I have listed some articles that say that using python threading with gunicorn can be a problem.

Here is my code:

```
import threading

def start_app():
    socketio.run(app, debug=True , use_reloader=False, host='0.0.0.0')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_app)
    second_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_function_every_thousand_and_one_minutes)
    third_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_function_every_twenty_one_minutes)
    fourth_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_function_every_five_minutes)
    first_thread.setDaemon(True)
    second_thread.setDaemon(True)
    third_thread.setDaemon(True)
    fourth_thread.setDaemon(True)
    first_thread.start()
    second_thread.start()
    third_thread.start()
    fourth_thread.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit(0)
```

The code works fine on localhost but my question is if it will work on gunicorn nginx server as well.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: If using threading doesn't pan out for you, one possible solution (on linux) is to setup rq or celery, then spin up a bunch of processes (rq or celery workers). Then send the functions to these processes to be run in paralell.